# Not sure why the method is not returning any value

Tags: php, javascript

I know I already have a similar post, but I can't for the life of me work out what is different between the two snippets - as I can only get the return value from the first example - but not the second example; both methods in the examples return a value.

What is even more bizarre (or frustrating) is that the PHP interpreter does not throw up any errors on the second example; it simply presents a blank screen. I am running on [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) and I believe "show errors", etc. is set to true.

First example (works perfectly):

```
<html>
    <?php
        function myMethod() {
            return "testing";
        }
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var val= "<?php echo myMethod(); ?>";
        document.write(val);
    </script>

</html>
```

Second example (note only the 'myMethod' function has changed):

```
<html>
    <?php
        function myMethod() {
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

            echo "<h2>Querying...</h2>\n";

            /* Get the port for the WWW service. */
            $service_port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');

            /* Get the IP address for the target host. */
            $address = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

            /* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
            $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
            if ($socket === false) {
                echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
            } else {
                echo "OK.\n";
            }

            echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
            $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
            if ($result === false) {
                echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
            } else {
                echo "OK.\n";
            }

            $in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
            $in .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
            $in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
            $out = '';

            echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
            socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
            echo "OK.\n";

            echo "Reading response:\n\n";
            while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
                echo $out;
                return 'test';
            }

            echo "Closing socket...";
            socket_close($socket);
            echo "OK.\n\n";
        }
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var val= "<?php echo myMethod(); ?>";
        document.write(val);
    </script>
</html>
```

Further to what [*the system* said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835596/not-sure-why-the-method-is-not-returning-any-value#comment20787654_14835596), it looks like the variable contains the correct data, but "document.write" does not seem to pipe it out to the browser view properly:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var val= "<h2>Querying...</h2>
    OK.
    Attempting to connect to '192.0.43.10' on port '80'...OK.
    Sending HTTP HEAD request...OK.
    Reading response:

    HTTP/1.0 302 Found
    Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
    Server: BigIP
    Connection: close
    Content-Length: 0

    test";

    document.write(val);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Open your developer console to read errors. Show the JavaScript that is rendered instead of the PHP.

Comment: One major flaw is that you'll be dumping all those `echo` statements into your JS variable assignment, BEFORE the return value gets echoed out. Any `"` in there will cause a JS syntax error. **NEVER** directly output PHP data into a JS code context without passing it through json_encode() first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the source code view of your browser. The script seems to work as **you** may expect (see below).

But note that **in JavaScript it is not possible to build multiline strings this way**.

When building a multiline string in JavaScript you'll have to do this:

```
var str  = "first line\n";
    str += "second line\n";
```

Or use the *join* function:

```
var str = [
  "first line",
  "second line"
].join("\n");
```

Here comes your output:

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var val= "<h2>Querying...</h2>
OK.
Attempting to connect to '192.0.43.10' on port '80'...OK.
Sending HTTP HEAD request...OK.
Reading response:

HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
Server: BigIP
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0

test";

document.write(val);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: @hek2mgl Could you provide an example then of handling this multiline data?

Answer (score 1):

Change all your echo to storing locally in a variable:

```
function myMethod()
{
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$temp = "<h2>Querying...</h2>\n";

/* Get the port for the WWW service. */
$service_port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');

/* Get the IP address for the target host. */
$address = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

/* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

$temp .= "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
    $temp .= "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
} else {
    $temp .= "OK.\n";
}

$in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
$out = '';

$temp .= "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
$temp .="OK.\n";

$temp .="Reading response:\n\n";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
    $temp .= $out;
    return 'test';

}

$temp .= "Closing socket...";
socket_close($socket);
$temp .= "OK.\n\n";
return $temp;
}
```

Comment: One other thing is to change the \n to <br /> if it's going to be written out to the document.

Answer (score 1):

Because JavaScript cannot support multiline text. You can return the output as an array with `json_encode`. Use it as an array in JavaScript:

```
<?php
    function myMethod()
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $return = array();

        $return[] = "<h2>Querying...</h2>\n";

        /* Get the port for the WWW service. */
        $service_port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');

        /* Get the IP address for the target host. */
        $address = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

        /* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        if ($socket === false) {
            $return[] = "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
        } else {
            $return[] = "OK.\n";
        }

        $return[] = "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
        $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
        if ($result === false) {
            $return[] = "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
        } else {
            $return[] = "OK.\n";
        }

        $in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $in .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
        $in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        $out = '';

        $return[] = "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
        socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
        $return[] = "OK.\n";

        $return[] = "Reading response:\n\n";
        while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
            $return[] = $out;
        }

        $return[] = "Closing socket...";
        socket_close($socket);
        $return[] = "OK.\n\n";

        return json_encode($return);
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var val= <?php echo myMethod(); ?>;

    for(i in val) {
        document.write(val[i] + '<br \/>');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code problem. It is in the HTML and JavaScript code, not in PHP.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        function myMethod()
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

            echo "<h2>Querying...</h2>\n";

            /* Get the port for the WWW service. */
            $service_port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');

            /* Get the IP address for the target host. */
            $address = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

            /* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
            $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
            if ($socket === false) {
                echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
            } else {
                echo "OK.\n";
            }

            echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
            $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
            if ($result === false) {
                echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
            } else {
                echo "OK.\n";
            }

            $in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
            $in .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
            $in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
            $out = '';

            echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
            socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
            echo "OK.\n";

            echo "Reading response:\n\n";
            while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
                echo $out;
                return 'test';
            }

            echo "Closing socket...";
            socket_close($socket);
            echo "OK.\n\n";
        }
    ?>
    <?php echo myMethod(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what did you change and why? What is the gist of the fix? What is the most important change? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14835801/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).